# WebSphere Database Federated Repository

Tags: security, db2, repository, websphere, federated

I'm trying to add a DB2 database repository to my federated repository. I'm using Websphere version 8.0.

I've been running through Paul Ilechko's instructions (http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0701_ilechko/0701_ilechko.html) and I keep getting stuck at Step 3 (Set up the repository by using this wsadmin command to create the wimDB tables). I keep getting this error:
com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.WIMSystemException: com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.WIMSystemException: CWWIM1999E  An exception occurred during processing: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

I did a search and it says I should set the Environment Variable DB2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH to /home/.../sqllib/java/ for the scopes Node=Node, Node=Node01, Node=CellManager.

I tested the data source connection via the WAS Console and it worked, so I don't know what I did wrong. Got any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily set required Environment variable.

1. Move to: `Environment ->  WebSphere Variables`
2. Set `Cell` scope
3. Create `DB2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH`